# KineticJS and transformations to a group (skew)

Tags: kineticjs, polygons

I'm having some trouble to figure out how to solve this.

I've a KineticGroup, that holds a polygon inside.
Also there is a button (KineticCircle) that stays on the right-top corner of the polygon, that user can drag to skew the polygon.

This is all working. My problem is:

the button get skewed with the polygon!
since the skew moves the top of the image to the button should follow the polygon, but it should keep it's original form.

I tried to move the button to a another group, inside the main group, and remove/add it, but it still skewed.

I also tried to make a parent group, holding the polygon group, and the button group, but then the button group would stay still, which is as bad for me.

Any Idea how to solve this?
Is there anyway to make a child group immune to it's parent group transformations?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about creating a custom KineticJS shape that's a rect  with skew controlled by property var's.

Then you don't have to skew the layer:

```
// skewRect properties to manipulate skew, etc.
var skewY=0;
var skewX=0;
var width=50;
var height=25;

var skewRect = new Kinetic.Shape({
  drawFunc: function(canvas) {
    var context = canvas.getContext();
    context.save();
    context.beginPath();
    context.transform(1, skewX, skewY, 1, 0, 0);
    context.fillRect(-width/2, -height/2, width, height);
    context.closePath();
    canvas.fillStroke(this);
    context.restore();
  },
  fill: 'red',
  stroke: 'black',
  strokeWidth: 4
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it didn't work very well here. There is a lot of things depending on the polygon, and skew isn't the only transformation it uses. But skew is the only that is making the buttons look strange. Is there any way to set the skew of the buttons inverse? in a way they would annulate each other?

Comment: Wou'da been good to know this info in your original question :p  So, are you saying you **need** the skewing to move your buttons into proper position (even though the buttons are thereby deformed)?  [originalRectX-originalButtonX != newRectX-newButtonX]  Or, do you just need the buttons to stay equidistant from the rectangle? [originalRectX-originalButtonX == newRectX-newButtonX]  And yes, you can unskew by negating the skew transform like this: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/72tEN/

Comment: Thank you! I think I'm finally getting somewhere. The idea is that the button stay over the right-top corner of the retangle all the time. So it should follow that corner all the skew, but not getting distorced

Comment: What would be the correct way to position the button/image in a corner of the transformed polygon?

Comment: I got it! Thank you very much for showing me the right track!